# Did Larry Gonick intend a companion book to Kokopelli & Co. In Attack of the Smart Pies?

Tags: comics, sequel

*Kokopelli & Co. In Attack of the Smart Pies* is a book, set in the world of Kokonino County. Larry Gonick was the author of the comic strip that ran in the *Muse* magazine by Cricket, which is set in that world - the book was written after the comic was started.

The book leaves several open ends - such as

> what were Emma's parents doing in Kokonino County?

However, *Kokopelli & Co.* is no longer running in *Muse*. Is/was there another planned book set in that world?

Comment: I sent a message to Mr. Gonick via http://www.larrygonick.com/contact/ to see if he can answer this for us. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Larry Gonick sent me a nice return email. Unfortunately, it sounds like there is not going to be another book.

[image: Reply from Larry Gonick, excerpted in the quote below]

> I did have a sequel in mind, but Muse and I parted ways, and it's not gonna happen. It was going to involve a spiritual fraud, maybe Mrs. Krishnamurti's brother, approaching the doughy villain in prison and convincing him that a religious conversion would help him obtain an early release in order to get his hands on the fortune.